# icetool read an input file with a date and overlay into another file

Tags: sorting, date, mainframe, jcl

I have an input file (80 char) with a date in position 1 to 10, format YYYY-MM-DD.  I will like to isolate that date and then write it to another existing file (use overlay maybe ??).  In this existing file I want the date to be replacing the YYYY-MM-DD.  this yyyy-mm-dd is located in position 59 in the output file.

I am not sure if we can perform this in one step only or we need two steps.

INPUT FILE (80 chars):
2018-06-28,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I will like to override the output file parameter YYYY-MM-DD.
OUTPUT FILE (80 chars):
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS

EXPECTED OUTPUT FILE RESULT:
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-06-28.QS

Comment: So file A is 80 charcters long with the date in the first 10 byte. You have another file (file B) that has the same format of date in position 59. You want to create an output record that contains all of the data from file B with the date from file A? Is there something these two files can be joined on?

Comment: I guess you want to use the Joinkey but my files doesn't have a key

Comment: it doesn't need to be a 'key' it just needs to be a unique identifier present in both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solve the problem:

```
//EXTRCT EXEC PGM=SORT                                            
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                              
//SORTIN DD 
        DSN=INPUT.DATE.CTL.FILE,DISP=SHR 
//SORTOUT DD 
        DSN=OUTPUT.FILE.TEST,    
//      DISP=(,CATLG),UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(TRK,(10,10),RLSE)       
//SYSIN DD *                                                      
 OPTION COPY                                                      
 OUTFIL REMOVECC,                                                      
 OUTREC FIELDS= 
      (C'FILE=/DATA/EXT/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.',59:1,10,         
       C'.QS         ')
/*                                                                
//
```

OUTPUT FILE Result will be:

FILE=/DATA/EXT/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2019-02-20.QS

I didn't want to use a join key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the expected result in one step using ICETOOL.

I've made the following assumptions:

1. Both input datasets are of LRECL 80.
2. There are same number of records in both input datasets.

**Records in input file 1:**

```
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST02_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST03_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST04_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST05_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST06_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.YYYY-MM-DD.QS
```

**Records in input file 2:**

```
2018-06-28,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-06-29,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-06-30,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-07-01,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-07-02,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-07-03,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Job:**

```
//Z31084A  JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID            
//SRTJK EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                   
//TOOLMSG DD SYSOUT=*                      
//DFSMSG DD SYSOUT=*                       
//INA DD DSN=Z31084.DATASET.A,DISP=SHR     
//INB DD DSN=Z31084.DATASET.B,DISP=SHR     
//JNA DD DSN=&&JNA,DISP=(,DELETE),         
//       SPACE=(CYL,(1,0),RLSE),           
//       DCB=(LRECL=84,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0) 
//JNB DD DSN=&&JNB,DISP=(,DELETE),         
//       SPACE=(CYL,(1,0),RLSE),           
//       DCB=(LRECL=84,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0) 
//OUT DD SYSOUT=*                          
//TOOLIN DD *                              
 SORT FROM(INA) TO(JNA) USING(CTL1)        
 SORT FROM(INB) TO(JNB) USING(CTL1)        
 SORT JKFROM TO(OUT) USING(CTL3)           
/*                                         
//CTL1CNTL DD *                            
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                          
 OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,80,81:SEQNUM,4,ZD)     
/*                                         
//CTL3CNTL DD *                            
 JOINKEYS F1=JNA,FIELDS=(81,4,A)           
 JOINKEYS F2=JNB,FIELDS=(81,4,A)           
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,58,F2:1,10,F1:69,12)
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                          
/*
```

**Output:**

```
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST01_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-06-28.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST02_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-06-29.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST03_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-06-30.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST04_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-07-01.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST05_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-07-02.QS
FILE=/DATA/EXT/RECEPTION/TEST06_DTE/PASSING_DTE_PARAM_CTL.2018-07-03.QS
```

As per my approach, I'm populating sequence numbers at the end of the record in both the input files and I'm using the sequence numbers as key in JOINKEYS application.

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: this answer also assumes that there is something that can be used as a join key. As per the comments, OP doesn't believe he has anything he can join on

Comment: This solution will also work.  I tried it.  I prefer not using any join keys